# swap index and value from enumerate()?

Tags: python

Python's `enumerate()` returns tuples of index and value:

```
enumerate('abc')
((0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'))
```

I'd like to get those tuples in `item,index` order (`('a', 0)`) instead.

How can I do that?

I'd like to use the reversed tuples to create a dictionary like:

```
{'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}
```

Comment: Simply: `{v: k for k,v in enumerate('abc')}`

Answer (score 11):

Use `dict` comprehension to reverse it:

```
result = {v: i for i, v in enumerate('abc')}
```

Addressing [@karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa)'s point - this will overwrite potentially repeated elements. If your string was `abca`, the index value assigned for `a` will contain `3`, not `0`.

Comment: You can change it to a list comprehension of reversed tuples in order to pass it to something like [`multidict.MultiDict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict) (Note that I haven’t used that package, but if there are issues with it I bet there are a gazillion other options).

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to use the `itertools` library:

```
import itertools
dict(zip('abc', itertools.count()))
```

`itertools.count()` is a generator object which generates 0, 1, 2... and the `zip` function just ... well zip the two together.

Comment: this is nice, like it!

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use zip:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> dict(zip(s, range(len(s))))
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always good, old-fashioned anonymous functions to do the work for you. It's not the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done.

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), enumerate('abc')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator:

```
>>> dict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate('abc'))
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with list comprehension :

```
new_data=((0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'))

print(tuple([(i[1],i[0])for i in new_data]))
```

output:

```
(('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2))
```